# How can I substitute the year in date from table

Tags: oracle

I want to substract 2 dates in oracle SQL developer, inc_date is stored as a date. I have the following code:

```
select to_date(to_char(i_date,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'),
       to_date(to_char('2023-') || to_char(i_date,'mm-')|| to_char(i_date,'dd-'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
       from data;
```

When I run the select like this, I get the result I want, even if I substract those 2, but even without substracting, when I scroll down the result, aproximately 250 rows in result I sudennly get the error message "date not valid for month specified". I understand the error message, but I dont understand why it gives me 250 of results I want and then the error pops up.

For reference, I cannot change the inc_date in data table itself and I have to have that year 2023. Simply said, I want to get as the result inc_date, where every row has a year 2023, but months and days stays the same.

Comment: You have to detect the row which causes the exception.  Write a loop with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, so you can print all processed cases and you can easily detect the value which causes the error.

Comment: Do you mean `inc_date` by using `i_date` ?

Comment: For **the first column** : If aim is just to display, then using `to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd')` is enough; if needed to keep as a date column, eg. as it is, then using `i_date` or `trunc(i_date)` ( depending on the existence of the time portion ) is enough. For **the second column** :  using `to_char('2023-')` conversion has no sense, `'2023-'` is already enough to use.

Comment: `2020-02-29` is a valid date, `2023-02-29` is not.

Answer (score 2):

As @PonderStibbons pointed out, the error suggests you have a leap day in your data, e.g. 2020-02-29. Your string manipulation would try to convert that to 2023-02-29, which is not a valid date.

> I dont understand why it gives me 250 of results I want and then the error pops up.

The results are being fetched in batches of 50 (the default in SQL Developer; you can change that in the preferences). The date and string manipulation is being done as part of the fetch, not when the query is parsed. The problematic date is appearing in the rows that happen to be fetched in the sixth batch (at the moment - there is no order-by clause so when you hit it is indeterminate). The first five are OK, and you get 50 rows for each of those five fetches, hence seeing 250 results. Then when it tries to fetch the next 50 rows it hits the problem date, which generates the error.

---

There are various ways to handle or skip the problematic date while still doing the string manipulation, including using the `default ... on conversion error` clause in [the `to_date()` call](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) in recent versions of Oracle. Exactly what you do would depend on how you want a leap day to be handled.

An alternative is to avoid string manipulation and do native date manipulation instead. You can use `add_months`, and base it on the difference between the year in the original date and 2023, multiplied by 12:

```
add_months(trunc(i_date), (2023 - extract(year from i_date)) * 12)
```

That will get the same result as your manipulation for most dates, and 2020-02-29 would convert as 2020-02-28.

I've left `trunc()` in there to set the time part of midnight, and as @BarbarosÖzhan said you can use that in the first part of your query too.

You don't really need to truncate either while you're treating them as dates for the subtraction, with this method, as the times will be the same and you'll still end up with a whole number of days when you subtract.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8-PxeKYB)

A more basic approach to the subtraction is just to multiply the difference in years by 365; but that won't account for leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     data (i_date)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT DATE '2020-08-15' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT DATE '2023-04-12' FROM DUAL)
```

Query:

```
  7  SELECT i_date, TO_DATE ('2023-' || TO_CHAR (i_date, 'mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') result
  8    FROM data;

I_DATE     RESULT
---------- ----------
15.08.2020 15.08.2023
12.04.2023 12.04.2023

SQL>
```

Comment: Or using literals in date format: `to_date(to_char(i_date, '"2023-"mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN i_date IS NULL
          THEN
             NULL
          ELSE
             TO_DATE ('2023-' || SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (i_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 6),
                      'YYYY-MM-DD')
       END
  FROM DUAL;
```

I think you have to handle the case in which i_date is NULL.

Comment: Or simply `TO_DATE(NVL2(i_date, '2023-'||TO_CHAR(i_date, 'mm-dd') ,null),'yyyy-mm-dd')`